# How to find NavigationViewItem from list of menuItems

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui

With the help of the following codes, I can find the NavigationViewItem I want

```
var item = navigationView.MenuItems
                            .OfType<NavigationViewItem>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(menuItem => (string)menuItem.Content == (string)args.InvokedItem);
```

but If a NavigationViewItem itself has other menuitems, this code is no longer valid.
How can I find the NavigationViewItem I want among all the menuitems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `NavigationViewItem` also has a collection of `MenuItems`, you could use some self referencing method like this:

```
(bool, NavigationViewItem?) SearchItems(List<NavigationViewItems> itemsToSearch, string argsInvokedItem) {

    foreach (var item in itemsToSearch)
    {
        if((string)item.Content == argsInvokedItem) {
            return (true, item);
        }

        if(item.MenuItems.Count > 0) {
            if(SearchItems(item.MenuItems, argsInvokedItem).Item1)
                return (true, item); 
        }
    }

    return (false, null);
}
```

And then call it like this:

`var result = SearchItems(navigationView.MenuItems, (string)args.InvokedItem)`